# Why do all users start in /root instead of their home directories after su as root?

Tags: centos, su, cwd

I feel like this should be straightforward but I've never seen anyone ask this that I can tell. The situation is pretty straight forward. Whenever I become a user, ie `su user` it always starts in /root directory instead of it's home directory. Let me show you.

```
[root@st-test2 ~]# grep "postgres" /etc/passwd
postgres:x:26:26:PostgreSQL Server:/var/lib/pgsql/:/bin/bash
[root@st-test2 ~]# su postgres
bash-4.2$ pwd
/root
[root@st-test2 ~]# ls -lhart /var/lib |grep postgres
drwx------.  4 postgres postgres   86 May  5 16:07 pgsql
```

So, you can see that the postgres user's home directory exists and that its set in /etc/passwd...but for some reason, they start in the root directory. This happens with every user that I have created and I have no idea why. I can't say that I've ever seen this happen before either.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you only give a username as argument, `su` changes user [without changing much else](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html):

> For backward compatibility, `su` defaults to not change the current
> directory and to only set the environment variables `HOME` and
> `SHELL` (plus `USER` and `LOGNAME` if the target user is not root).

So `su postgres` stays in the same directory. However since `HOME` is set to the new user’s home directory, `cd` *will* take you to the right place.

To log in and start from the user’s default directory, you need to ask `su` to start a login shell set up appropriately:

```
su -l postgres
```

or its common synonym,

```
su - postgres
```

Comment: I guess that is it. My employer has it setup where su - also goes to user's home directory and I thought that my test servers not doing that was causing an issue, but now I am thinking that my employer has an alias somewhere and also that su - not going to the home directory didn't cause an issue. Thanks for the explanation! I really should just read the man file more often.

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to name aliases differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your employer may have changed this because Debian changed the `su` behavior since Buster. [NewInBuster](https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster) I also created the `alias su='su -'`